# Debugging symlinked node modules with "chrome" type launch configuration

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, node-modules, vscode-debugger

I've been using VS Code on macOS to develop a Vue.js app, with integrated Chrome debugging. This all works fine, but I also have a separate module I’m developing in conjunction, and it’s been symlinked in with `npm link`. This works great, except VS Code doesn’t let me set breakpoints in my modules’s code (they appear as “unbound” breakpoints).

The [solution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_can-i-debug-if-im-using-symlinks) to this is to specify `runtimeArgs` in `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "vuejs: chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
        "breakOnLoad": true,
        "runtimeArgs": ["--preserve-symlinks", "--preserve-symlinks-main"],
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
          "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
        }
      },
    ]
  }
```

But this still doesn’t work.The only examples I can find online show type `node`, not type `chrome` launch configurations. I’m not sure if Chrome debugging doesn’t support this option, or if there’s something else wrong.